# Setup ArcGIS 10.6.1 SDK runtime in Visual studio 2017

Tags: arcobjects, sdk

I have ArcGIS 10.6.1 and I wish to setup ArcGIS Add-in in Visual Studio 2017 community edition.

I installed Visual Studio followed by ArcGIS Desktop. Then I installed ArcGIS 10.6.1 runtime SDK.

However, ArcGIS link is not visible in Visual Studio.

Comment: That is odd, the SDK would not install if it did not recognize your Visual Studio version... When you open Visual Studio and select 'new project' is there no ArcGIS option available? Can you include a screen shot of your 'new project' dialog in Visual Studio please. Are you trying to write an addin for ArcGIS or a runtime application? If you want to write an addin you will need the ArcGIS for Desktop SDK, from what you have said in your question you have installed runtime which you may not be licensed for.

Comment: Can you confirm which API you are interested in? Runtime and ArcObjects are completely different.

Comment: I am interested in doing programming in Visual Studio using ArcObjects.

Comment: You need to install the Desktop SDK for 10.6 not Runtime 10.6, you should be able to obtain a copy through your my Esri account if it's not on your Desktop install media.

Comment: Is ArcGIS Pro SDK 2.1 same as Desktop SDK 10.6. For Desktop SDK only runtime version is available. Thanks

Comment: Hi Michael, I downloaded ArcObject SDK , it worked well and ArcGIS is visible in Visual Studio. Thanks for all your help.